# 'LinearStrokeCap' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no longer used, please use barRadius instead

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**I am creating Linear Percent Indicator. I want to achieve rounded borders around it.**

**Expected Result Vs. Actual Result**

[image]

## My Code

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
            linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
            progressColor: Colors.blue[400],
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
 ),
```

## Error

[image]

## Any Solution

Any solution to use barRadius as LinearStrokeCap?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `barRadius` instead of `linearStrokeCap`. as `LinearStrokeCap` is deprecated they are suggesting to use `barRadius`.

Updated code :

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
  lineHeight: 30,
  percent: 0.7,
  barRadius: const Radius.circular(16),
  progressColor: Colors.blue[400],
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
),
```

Output:

[image]